How to avoid stagnating gameplay in a Non-Linear game?
In open world games, the progression, in most cases, is Non-Linear leading to players either going through the game at an extremely fast pace, or others stagnating without understanding what to do.
Im quite interested in why some players go farther much faster than others, but what I am more interested in is the players that reach a point in a video game and stagnate.
I ask this in the perspective of an open world, rpg-like game where players go through the land gaining all sorts of resources making custom and unique tools themselves to combat different problems, such as transport and combat. There is not concept of levels or skill points and the intention is to make the game about how the player solves a specific problem.
I find in a lot of games that have open world aspects, players get stumped on how to do things on the creative side when playing, hitting a wall and giving up far too fast.
Why does stagnation happen in open world games?
This leads into a question of:
"How would I be able to avoid a stagnation?"

Can you elaborate which dimension is stagnating? "Quests done per hour" or "reaction time" or "time to solve a standard puzzle" or "average attempts needed to kill a boss" or "money earned per session"? I think answers may differ from case to case...

This may be hard to answer in a satisfying way that applies generally to all open world games. If we look at a specific game, we can probably identify specific features that contribute, but those features may differ from game to game. If you're working on combatting stagnation in your game in planning/development, it would help to edit your question to walk us through how your specific game works, and where you're concerned stagnation may arise. Then we should be able to offer more actionable advice about how to improve your unique case.

"Why some players go farther much faster than others" -- probably because the same thing happens in life. Some people assign meaning to the events of their lives, and that perceived meaning keeps them going... even if there was no objective meaning to those events in the first place. Others fall by the wayside, becoming lost or discouraged. Existential philosophy is more likely to give you deeper answers to these sorts of questions.

I made it a bit more specific, sorry if it was too general before

I read the question three times and I still don't understand what exactly it means with "stagnating". Do you mean just stop playing the game? Before or after discovering all the content? Or that they keep playing the game, but without making meaningful progress? Then what are they doing in the game?

Your example seems to be asking "how to avoid players getting stumped?" Answers to your previous question already touch on this. What specifically are you looking for beyond that advice?

You mentioned "open world, rpg-like game" but specified "There is no concept of levels or skill points". This makes it especially hard to grasp what kind of game you're imagining because to a lot of people, "rpg-like" necessarily entails that the player character gains some manner of numerical advantage as tasks are completed. Are you disclaiming levels and skill points specifically, or numerical progression in general?

Numerical progression in general, the idea would be to obtain items with abilities which modify stats in relation to x.

There are at two main diametric forces at play:
Boredom and Frustration.

You must learn what motivates your players to avoid both of these conditions.
Varying challenge levels, rewards and achievements are the traditional solutions.
Maybe try opening new aspects of game play after a certain point or event in the game.

However, at some point all aspects of a game become stagnate.  Look at Ultima Online and WOW.  Both great online games, but no longer mainstream AAA titles.
Another example is Epic Games' "Unreal 4" as a community project release.

Too much of anything becomes boring after a while.
